# How to return json/xml from Spring Boot @Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'm trying to return JSON/XML from a function of my Controller. First I was using @RestController and it worked good, but now I need to change to @Controller, because I will use also some other functions and pass there some objects for my view.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/game")
public class ViewController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/statistic", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public GamerData[] getStatistic() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            String uri_get_statistic = "http://localhost:8081/statistic/";
            ResponseEntity<GamerData[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri_get_statistic, GamerData[].class);
            GamerData[] statisticData = response.getBody();
            return statisticData;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

After I've changed to Controller I get error 404 not found. With RestController I've got json. (GamerData is just a class with 2 simple fields (int and String), setters, getters, consructor).

UPDATE:
I've added `@ResponseBody` to my function, but now I have Internal Server error
`Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class [Lgame.mainservice.mvc.GamerData;] with preset Content-Type 'null']`

Comment: *I will use also some other functions* It seems you might be misunderstanding what the difference is. What are you trying to do that you think requires omitting `@RestController`? (Also note that in general, it's best to avoid using arrays and use `List<GamerData>` instead.)

Comment: @V_swan check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for answers, I've added `@ResponceBody` annotation to my function and removed "produces" part from `@RequestMapping` annotation and my function works great:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/statistic", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public GamerData[] getStatistic() {
    //function code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add @ResponseBody like

```
public @ResponseBody GamerData[] getStatistic....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/statistic", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@ResponseBody  // add this one
public GamerData[] getStatistic() {}
```